# Can I change a \def inside a \foreach loop without making it visible to the whole document?

Tags: foreach, grouping, scoping

I understand that a `\foreach` loop creates a group and local definitions are, of course, local.

Is there a way to skip just one level of the scoping? I mean I wish to make a local change inside the loop to be visible outside, but not making it truly global.

I'm working in a `newcommand` and I have a local variable which I don't want to be global.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{%
    \def\myvar{X} % local
    \foreach \v in {1, ..., 3}{
        (\v;\myvar)
        \global\def\myvar{W}
    }
    -- in mycommand: \myvar % I need this updated
}

\begin{document}

\mycommand  
    
myvar: \myvar % I wish for an 'undefined control sequence' here...

\end{document}
```

Adding a `\begingroup ... \endgroup` pair makes no difference, since `\global` does exactly what it is designed to do.

Also, I know this isn't a really big deal, but my curiosity and my structured-programming soul made me ask!

Comment: `\let\myvar=\undefined` or `\global\let\myvar=\undefined` works (assuming `\undefined` is actually undefined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, provided you don't want to use the original meaning (if any) of `\myvar` inside the loop.

TeX is perfectly happy to `\let` something to something undefined, so the first instruction keeps the original meaning (possibly none) and the traling one restores it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{%
    \let\jandermyvar\myvar
    \def\myvar{X} % local
    \foreach \v in {1, ..., 3}{
        (\v;\myvar)
        \global\def\myvar{W}
    }
    -- in mycommand: \myvar % I need this updated
    \let\myvar\jandermyvar
}

\begin{document}

\mycommand

myvar: \myvar % I wish for an 'undefined control sequence' here...

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, it's better not to mix meanings: use a different name in the loop.

Depending on your actual needs, there are different methods for avoiding global declarations in loops.

Comment: Interesting how to _undef_ something...